# Stocks broker compensation upon error

Tags: stocks, broker

I have a stock plan from my employer, which includes RSU vesting on certain dates through E-trade's services. Currently, E-trade has technical issues, which are preventing me (and some other employees in my company) from getting our RSUs vested, causing them to miss the agreed date of the vesting. The agreed date is precise and does not include a "within X business days" clause. Having in mind how fast the stock markets change, there will be a difference in the price of the stocks when they get vested. In the case where the price has dropped, does that classify as a loss or missed opportunity induced by their technical difficulties and is that something that can be pursued?

Comment: Interesting question, but unless you had planned to sell between the scheduled and actual vesting, you haven't actually lost anything due to the delayed vesting. Also consider from the other side - if the price went *up* after the scheduled vesting, would you expect Etrade to keep the difference for themselves?

Comment: That was exactly what I was going to do. I usually sell them off right away and use the profits to buy other stocks. When I say compensation, I do not necessarily mean money. Also, I did give quite some thought on the other scenario. It is possible, that if I were to sell the stocks at a lower price, I would still get some funds that I would be able to buy other stocks that may or may not have been cheaper earlier on (that also applies to the drop scenario).